# add a class to an option in options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add a class("has-versions) to an option element in my select tag depending on the option item. How can I add that class?

```
 = select_tag 'project_version_id', "<option value='' disabled>-optional select version-</option>".html_safe + options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.current_project.project_versions, :id, :name, @test_case.script.try(:project_version_id))
```

I need it to be something like this:

```
<select name="project_version_id" id="project_version_id">
  <option disabled="" value="">-optional select version-</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="19">NOOB SAIBOT</option>
  <option class="has-versions" value="20">PEW PEW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: make your own helper to generate options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:
2 improvements:

- Use `:include_blank` for a "starter" value
- Pass the `:class` when generating the options for select

.

```
<%= select 
  "new_something", 
  "project_version_id", 
  options_for_select(["Item11", ["Item 2",{:class=>'has-versions'}]]),
  {:include_blank => '-optional select version-'} %>
```

Hint: You can use `collect` on an array to generate the `options_for_select` as desired.

Comment: so there's no way to add a class with using options_from_collection_for_select? That's what i was asking

Comment: No. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select.